# Can StructureMap load modules/assemblies on demand?

Tags: assemblies, inversion-of-control, structuremap

Are there facilities in StructureMap that will allow me to load services from other modules (assemblies) on demand like it's done in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Like This?

```
            Assembly ass = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        Container.Configure(x => x.Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.Assembly(ass); 
            scan.LookForRegistries();
        }));
```